# knockout - get value from parent array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

below is a snippet of my HTML containing some knockout bindings. If the first/outer foreach loop goes through an array called tradesObservableArray that contains a key called "ThreadID", how can I get that value where I have: ****$root.ThreadID****? Please note that $root.ThreadID is in an inner foreach loop.

Basically, **$root.ThreadID** returns undefined. I've also tried **$parent.ThreadID** with the same result.

Thanks in advance ...

```
 <div id="tradesThread" data-bind="foreach: tradesObservableArray">

            <table>
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: $root.filesObservableArray">
                    <tr id="tradeRow">
                        <td data-bind="visible: $root.tradeRowFiles(**$root.ThreadID**, CommentID)"><span data-bind="text: FileName"></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
           </div>
```

Comment: What datatype is `ThreadID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ThreadID` is an observable object then you can get its value by calling:

```
$parent.ThreadID()
```

Comment: Hi ! When I try $parent.Thread(), I get the following error: $parent.ThreadID is not a function. Basically, within the tradesObservableArray, I have a bunch of key/values. One of the keys is ThreadID. Also, the datatype is INT.

Comment: If it's truly just a numeric value and not an observable then `$parent.ThreadID` should do the trick.  Could you set up a jsfiddle to show your error with real data?

Comment: Arghh, found the problem. It's '$parent.threadID' ... small t, not capital ... sorry about that Ek0nomik ...  STACK OVERFLOW: feel free to delete this thread ...